# oracle RMAN backup partitions

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-backups, database-partitioning, rman

I have some partitioned tables based on the date of insertion of row.

I want to take back up of only a select partitions from the database using RMAN.

Is that possible ?

After taking the backup, can I delete those partitions from the database.

Comment: why would you need this?

Answer (score 0):

RMAN can individually backup tablespaces. Or you can do individual datafiles and cannot do it for partitions.

You can restore and recover datafile or tablespace in RMAN but not table. You cannot backup just a table will RMAN.

If you have to take the partition backup then you can assign that particulat table to a tablespace afer which you can backup the tablespace (Table).

You can issue  BACKUP TABLESPACE ;

This way you will be performing a Backup of Tablespaces as this tablespace have only one table, you will backup a specific table only.